# How can I find numbers based on the cityname twilio using c# API?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to find local numbers based on the cityname same as we have in twilio "buy a number" interface search by location using C# API.

I need something as in the below link.

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local-get-basic-example-5

In link the solution is for area code not for the city.

Comment: Find a phone number in the London prefix (+4420) which is SMS-enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The API doesn't supply a city search, however, you could use geolocation to get the latitude and longitude of the city you are interested in and then use the `NearLatLong` filter combined with the `Distance` filter to find numbers near the city you are interested in. Check out the [advanced number search filters](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local-get-advanced-filters) and the example of getting [numbers within 50 miles of San Francisco](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers#local-get-advanced-example-1).

Let me know if that helps at all.